# Reference for numerical conditions for algebraic properties to hold

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request

Please any one suggest some good books provided the knowledge that how to find no of subgroups,  no of generators, no of ideals maximals or prime, no of group or gings homomorphism, numerical conditions in order to be integral domain or fields ie all numerical approach toward abstract algebra.

Comment: Contemporary Abstract Algebra ,Joseph Gallian

Comment: What do you mean by "number of" ? Many examples ?